# GGX importance sampling formula derivation

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I'm reading [this paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Esrm/publications/EGSR07-btdf.pdf) and I'm struggling to work out a formula.
Maybe you can help me spot what I'm doing wrong.

In particular, I need to know how to get from equation (33) to equation (35).

[image]

[image]

Let me explain a little what this is all about.
So we have an infinite flat surface with normal $\vec{n}$. That surface, at the microscopic level, has some roughness $\alpha_g$ that makes the surface normal uneven.

$D(\vec{m})$ is a probability density function that tells us the probability to find a spot with micro-normal $\vec{m}$.

$\theta_m$ is the angle between the macro-normal and the micro-normal (i.e, $\theta_m = acos(\vec{m} \cdot \vec{n})$)

$\chi^+(x)$ is 1 if $x > 0$ and 0 otherwise.

The equation (35) is used for importance sampling for $D(\vec{m}) |\vec{m} \cdot \vec{m}|$. It gives the sampling direction given a random variable uniformly distributed between [0, 1], $\xi_1$.

### This is how I attempt to solve the problem

First I'm going to compute the cumulative distribution function for $D(\vec{m}) |\vec{m} \cdot \vec{m}|$.

$$
D(\vec{m}) |\vec{m} \cdot \vec{m}| =
\frac{\alpha \chi^+(\vec{m} \cdot \vec{n})|\vec{m} \cdot \vec{m}|}
{\pi cos^4{\theta_m}(\alpha² + \tan(\theta_m))^2} =
\frac{\alpha cos^2{\theta_m}}
{\pi cos^4{\theta_m}(\alpha² + \tan(\theta_m))^2} =
\frac{\alpha}
{\pi cos^2{\theta_m}(\alpha² + \tan(\theta_m))^2}
$$

Now we compute de cumulative distribution function:

$$
C(\theta_m) = 
\int_0^{\theta_m}
\frac{\alpha}
{\pi cos^2{\theta_m}(\alpha^2 + \tan(\theta_m))^2}
dx =
\frac{\alpha^2}{\pi}
\int_0^{\theta_m}
\frac{1}
{cos^2{\theta_m}(\alpha^2 + \tan(\theta_m))^2}
dx
$$

I have tried to solve this integral with Maxima, but it seems to be stuck forever.

```
integrate(a^2/(%pi * cos(x)^2 * (a^2+tan(x)^2)^2), x, 0, x)
```

The same happens with Wolfram Alpha.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Over the years, you may already know the answer. At that time, your missing is the wrong simplified spherical integral.

$$ 
C(X,Y) = \int_{0}^{Y}\int_{0}^{X}PDF(x,y) * sin(y)*dx*dy
$$

<sup>$$
C(X,Y) = \int_{0}^{Y}\int_{0}^{X}D(\vec N \cdot \vec {Nm})*(\vec N \cdot \vec {Nm}) * sin(y)*dx*dy \\
\vec {Nm} = sph2cart(x,y,1) 
$$</sup>

Because the integrand associated only elevation'y', so eliminate azimuth'x'[0,pi*2].

$$
C(Y) = 2\pi * \int_{0}^{Y}PDF(y) * sin(y)*dy \\
C(Y) = 2\pi * \int_{0}^{Y}D(cos(y))*cos(y) * sin(y)*dy \\
$$

Then input "2*r^2*sin(y)/(cos(y)^3 * (r^2 + tan(y)^2)^2)" into [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/)
$$
Problem:\\
\int \frac{2*r^2*sin(y)}{cos(y)^3*(tan(y)^2 + r^2)^2} * dy \\
Apply\ linearity:\\
= 2*r^2 * \int \frac{sin(y)}{cos(y)^3*(tan(y)^2 + r^2)^2} * dy \\
 \\
Now\ solving:\\
\int \frac{sin(y)}{cos(y)^3*(tan(y)^2 + r^2)^2} * dy \\
Rewrite/simplify\ using\ trigonometric/hyperbolic\ identities:\\
= \frac{1}{2} * \int \frac{2*sec(y)^2 * tan(y)}{(tan(y)^2 + r^2)^2} * dy \\
Substitute\ u = tan(y)^2 + r^2,\ du = 2*sec(y)^2*tan(y)*dy:\\
= \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u^2}*du \\
... \\
... \\
... \\
2*r^2 * \int \frac{sin(y)}{cos(y)^3*(tan(y)^2 + r^2)^2} * dy \\
= - \frac{r^2}{tan(y)^2 + r^2}
$$

Final input "solve y = - Divide[Power[r,2],Power[tan(40)x(41),2 ]+Power[r,2]] + Divide[Power[r,2],Power[tan(40)0(41),2]+Power[r,2]] for x" into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=solve+y+%3D+-+Divide%5BPower%5Br%2C2%5D%2CPower%5Btan%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2C2+%5D%2BPower%5Br%2C2%5D%5D+%2B+Divide%5BPower%5Br%2C2%5D%2CPower%5Btan%5C%2840%290%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Br%2C2%5D%5D+for+x)
$$
Input \quad interpretation \\
solve \quad y = - \frac{r^2}{tan(x)^2 + r^2} + \frac{r^2}{tan(0)^2 + r^2} \quad for \quad x \\
Results \\
x = \pi*n - atan(\frac{r*\sqrt y}{\sqrt{1 - y}}) \quad and \quad r^3*y+r != r*y and ... \\
x = \pi*n + atan(\frac{r*\sqrt y}{\sqrt{1 - y}}) \quad and \quad r^3*y+r != r*y and ... \\
$$

Your idea is correct "Inverse CDF".